# How to handle VOIP Status Bar (back to app) in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, voip, quickblox

I am using QuickBlox for VOIP calling. When I press Home button, while being in call, iOS show red status bar, when clicked, it take the user back to app.

**Question**: How I can know user came back to app by clicking on that red status bar?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html

I think `applicationDidBecomeActive:` and `applicationWillEnterForeground:` might help you